# Draw Latitude/Longitude points/lines on screen in Android, offline, without real maps functionality

Tags: java, android, geolocation, maps, coordinates

I'm developing an Android application (in Java/Android Studio) which receives Latitude/Longitude coordinates from a network source, which it has to plot on the screen. The appearance should be much like one of those old 'green-on-black radar screens'.

**Constraints/Requirements:**

- The application doesn't have connection to the internet. (never)
- I need to draw points, (custom) markers, lines, and polygons, all based on latitude/longitude information.
- The background should be plain black. i.e. no map tiles or anything.

Does anyone know of a library which can help me achieve this?

**Other options I'm considering:**

- Manual direct conversion to screen X/Y coordinates. *This seems problematic (?) as you get closer to the poles.*
- Converting all points to polar coordinates (bearing/distance) from a center position. And then convert these polar coordinates to screen X/Y coordinates. *Should work for the radar-style application, but seems cumbersome when there's a good library available.*

I'm really interested in what you guys think and if you have suggestions on how to address this.

Thanks a million!

Kind regards,

Joost

Comment: see [SphericalMercatorProjection](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/projection/SphericalMercatorProjection.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. I'm completely new to Android Development so I'm still having a hard time navigating through the available resources and documentation.

Comment: this is a support library, more: http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/